# Getting error of missing protobuf while connecting MySQL to Python in Windows

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

While installing `mysql-connector` on cmd prompt using command:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

It said installed successfully, but gave this error:

> mysql-connector-python 8.0.15 requires protobuf>=3.0.0, which is not
> installed windows 8.1

I can't find install instructions for the right version of `protobuf`, that might be needed.

Later, while making db connection in `pycharm` using statement

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host, user, passwd)
```

I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Any idea how to proceed? Using Python 3.7 on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

To install `protubuf` using pip use,

`pip3 install protubuf` has version of `3.6.1`.

And for mysql `ImportError`, a package `ConfigParser` has been renamed to `configparser` for Python 3.

For that install `configparser`using pip again after installing `mysql`

```
pip3 install configparser
```